# How to merge/concat dataframe and dummies without duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe, with pair of columns containing categorical data (they are the same, differing only by the amount of values for their categories); and I've made two sets of dummies for those two columns, viz:

```
dummies1 = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['col1'].isin(columns_valuecounts_top3.index)], columns=['col1', 'col2']) 
dummies2 = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['col2'].isin(columns_valuecounts_top3.index)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

But, instead of creating two datasets with dummies ONLY (without all other original df's columns), the aforementioned action created a new dataset for each variable, adding dummy columns to them *(the amount of values (rows) was different, though, because those dummies were created for two columns at the same time - it was expected, so not a problem)*.

I wanted:

```
| col1 | col1_a | col1_b |
| col2 | col2_a | col2_b |
```

Instead I got:

```
name | salary | col1 | col1_a | col2_b |
name | salary | col2 | col2_a | col2_b |
```

And therefore, when I concatenated them, instead of receiving this:

```
name | salary | col1 | col2 | col1_a | col1_b | col2_a | col2_b |
```

I got:

```
name | salary | col1 | col2 | name | salary | col1 | col1_a | col1_b | name | salary | col2 | col2_a | col2_b |
```

And that's definitely not what I wanted.
How can I get dummies properly and add them to dataframe? It would definitely be a mess to delete those columns one by one, as originally there are 30-40 of them in my df. I think there can be a better solution, so I humbly ask the community for an advice.

Guys are asking for a reproducible example; I'll try my best:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['hacker', 'scamer', 'breaker', 'coder', 'leaker', 'tester', 'helper', 'leader'], 'salary': [1000, 1250, 250, 1001, 2500, 1500, 500, 3000], 'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e'], 'col2': ['b', 'c', 'c', Nan, 'b', 'd', Nan, 'a']})
```

Below is what I expect to get after creating dummies and merging it with the df:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df, dummies1, dummies2], axis=1)
```

```
   name | salary | col1 | col1_a | col1_b | col1_c | col1_d | col1_e | col2 | col2_a | col2_b | col2_c | col2_d | col2_e |
 hacker |   1000 |    a |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |    b |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
 scamer |   1250 |    b |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |    c |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |
breaker |    250 |    b |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |    c |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |
  coder |   1001 |    a |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |  Nan |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
 leaker |   2500 |    c |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |    b |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
 tester |   1500 |    a |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |    d |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |
 helper |    500 |    d |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |  Nan |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
 leader |   3000 |    e |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |    a |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example to your question ?

Comment: Kind of difficult, as there are huge amounts, like tens of thousands.

Comment: What about `print(df.sample(5).to_dict("list"))` ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but you know it's like more than 100 columns at once, not enough place for a comment.
I guess, it can be represented as ```df['col1'] = pd.Series(a, a, a, b, b, c)``` and ```df['col2'] = pd.Series(a, b, b, b, c, c)```

Comment: @abokey, I have added some example in the end of the post.

Comment: No worries. So based on the example you gave, what would we your expected output ?

Comment: @abokey, Well, I guess, it would be 

```name | salary | col1 | col2 | col1_a | col1_b | col1_c | col2_a | col2_b | col2_c |```

```hacker |  1000 |  a |   a |    1 |    0 |    0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |```
and so on. Well, I hope you got the point, the orientation here in comments is a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the dummy value, you can pass only that column into `pd.get_dummies`.

```py
dummies1 = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['col1'].isin(columns_valuecounts_top3.index), 'col1']) 
dummies2 = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['col2'].isin(columns_valuecounts_top3.index), 'col2'])
```